# Getting incorrect sytax error with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have what I think should be a simple question but for the life of me cannot solve it myself. I'm just trying to do a simple search on a table.

```
Select *
From dbo.Case
Where dbo.Case.CountyName='Milwaukee'
```

I keep getting this error:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Case'.

I've also tried taking off the "dbo" and it still does not work.

What am I doing wrong? (Using SQL Server 2008)

Answer (score 7):

`CASE` [is a reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx). You will need to enclose it in `[]` to use as a an identifier such as a database, column, or table name:

```
Select *
From dbo.[Case]
Where dbo.[Case].CountyName='Milwaukee'
```

Answer (score 4):

`Case` [is a reserved word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) in SQL, so you need to put square brackets around it.